The button indexes are different between two controllers. Is there a work around?
I found that when you connect a controller, the buttons have a code. When I run console.log(navigator.getGamepads()[0].buttons), the A button on a Nintendo Switch Pro controller (I can't remember exactly what it was named) is listed as index 0, while a Game Cube controller lists the A button as index 1. Is there a way to tell if I'm pressing A, even if the index button on a different controller is different?

"press a to start the game" could work. Store what button is pressed, treat that as a.

@DaniëlvandenBerg This sounds terrible lol. Not only will this not tell you the button codes for the other buttons but what if a user instinctively presses like the START button or something? Now they have START mapped to A :P

Usually one would do this with a controller map. A controller map is basically a text file that maps from the controller button codes into a common format. For example SDL uses this file which contains the controller UUID, controller name, and which codes map to which key in the SDL controller interface.
I don't know what framework you are using but look up if your framework has a similar file. If they do not you will probably need to do this manually, or perhaps if you are lucky you can adapt the SDL file to fit your needs, but check the license first, it might not be free to use*.
*As of writing this answer the license is a zlib license which does allow editing as long as it is clearly mentioned that it has been edited.

So if I use this, I have to clarify I edited it (only if I actually did edit it)?

@Alex The exact license can be found here and it's probably best to refer to it rather than me :)
